# Gather mutliple entries from one table then union them for one output (activity feed)

Tags: php, mysql

So I have just learned to properly create a union query in mysql (see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08f1cc/1) to pull like items from the database so I can output them at once. But now I have run into a problem where I am not sure how to create the solution.

I am trying to create an activity feed to be displayed based upon the people someone is following. (basically like twitter and facebook) But I do not know how to start where I pull all the people that they follow (within user_actions), then get the latest of all the activity they post (like with the above union) sorted by timestamp. Of course someone can follow alot of people and that is what makes it alot more complicated. I have never taken on a query or project of this size.

Any help on how to do this and the thought process I must have to do this will left a lot.

**EDIT:**
SQLFIDDLE is having website issues

Current query that I have used for the union example.

```
(SELECT
            `id`      AS `id`,
            `user_id` AS `user_id`,
            `edittimestamp` AS `timestamp`,
            `content` AS `data`,
            `title`             AS `title`,
            `dataimgs`             AS `dataimgs`,
            'project'        AS `type`
        FROM `projects`
        WHERE store_id='1' and timestamp > '2015-07-24 17:29:12')

        UNION
        (SELECT
            `id`      AS `id`,
            `user_id` AS `user_id`,
            `timestamp` AS `timestamp`,
            `post` AS `data`,
            `title`             AS `title`,
            `dataimgs`             AS `dataimgs`,
            'post'       AS `type`
        FROM `user_posts`
        WHERE store_id='1' and timestamp > '2015-07-24 17:29:12')
        ORDER BY timestamp
        LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for creating the Fiddle, but I can't open it (at least not right now).  Could you also include the query or queries you have done so far in your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the union query to as an edit. Tried to put the mysql dump but the code block did not want to work

Comment: What is your intention with including `LIMIT 10`?  The query looks like it should run, what is the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking about setting this to 20, since the script was going to be working so hard, instead but I was thinking about implementing a infinite scroll, once you reach the bottom it loads more. Basically how facebook does too. Is there a better way to load the data?

Comment: Try reading about using `LIMIT` with an offset (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).  This is how pagination is usually done in MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking about this but then I would not need the timestamp WHERE clause. I thought that if I used the WHERE clause I can get the last item from that point instead of loading what was already loaded. Lets say the scroll was loaded 3 times already, then it would not have to read/write (20 x 3) 60 items. This should also eliminate any duplicates showing up on the feed if someone posts a update while looking though their feed. of course I am going to need to use milliseconds on the timestamp to make sure I would not be skipping any items